# Using c++ to count number of times a letter appeared in your work and their percentage

Tags: c++

The programme is about getting the number of letters in words of your programme with their ratings to know which appeared most.example "I stay in Ohio" from the sentence we can see it is made up of a group of letters and we are to know the number times a letter appeared ahbd their ratings in percentage

Comment: Those are some interesting details. I always wanted to know what the "programme" was about.

Comment: Look up `std::isalpha`, `std::toupper`, and `std::map`. Think `std::map<char, int>`

Answer (score -1):

You can create `std::vector<std::pair>` that contains the pair of information, first would be a letter and the second one would be the number how many they are in sentence. You can go through each char in sentence and check if it is equal `0x0` if not, then add the letter to `first` field in `std::pair` in `std::vector` and count how many the letter appears in sentence changing the letter with `0x0`. After that go to the next letter until the sentence ends. There you will have a vector containing pairs of information: `first` - the letter, `second` - how many times it appeared.

Comment: Thanks dude am grateful

Comment: Look up `std::isalpha`, `std::toupper`, and `std::map`. Think `std::map<char, int>`

Comment: No reason for the `pair`.  Make the `vector` of integers.  Use the characters as index into the vector.  Increment the value in the slot.